# What is a Fractional Remainder in the context Python's division always returning a float?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

What is a Fractional Remainder in Python? In the context of division in Python:

```
>>> 2 / 1
2.0
```

Excerpt from the book Learning Python by Mark Lutz to provide the context to the question:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7Y6E.png)

Comment: The fractional remainder is a result of integer division. `/` does floating-point division in Python 3, there is no remainder. You get the remainder of integer division by using the modulo operator `%`.

Comment: The question title doesn't quite make sense. Either you ask "what is...?" or you ask "why is ... always returning a float?".

Comment: The relevant context should be part of the question as text.

Comment: You're right. The question in fact does not make much sense without reading the attached excerpt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best interpretation of “always retains fractional remainders” is the author means that, in Python 3, the `/` operator performs a floating-point division. The author is trying to say that the fractional part of the quotient, not the remainder, is retained. E.g., in `7/4`, the result is 1.75, keeping the .75, rather than 1, discarding the .75. The author is incorrect to call this a “fractional remainder.”

Answer (score 0):

The Modulo expression returns remainders

```
2 % 1 => 0
3 % 2 => 1
5 % 3 => 2
```

According to text, they are explaining how Python reads expressions.

```
 5 / a + b ==> (5 / a) + b
```

Where:

```
 5 / (a + b) != 5 / a + b
```